# how to draw two connected rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw two rectangles (or two shapes in general) so that they touch each other. Below is the minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1.00in, fill=cyan] (a) {}
node[rectangle,draw,fill=magenta] (b) [left=of a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `left= 0pt of a`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1.00in, fill=cyan] (a) {}
node[rectangle,draw,fill=magenta] (b) [left= 0pt of a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or `left= -\pgflinewidth of a` if you want the edges to overlap:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1.00in, fill=cyan] (a) {}
node[rectangle,draw,fill=magenta] (b) [left= -\pgflinewidth of a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As  **Qrrbrbirlbel** mentioned in a comment, another way to have the edges to overlap is to set `outer sep` (or `outer xsep`, `outer ysep`) to zero which puts the anchors in the middle of the edge's line.

If this should apply to all nodes, you could better use the `node distance` key for `tikzpicture` (or a `scope`); something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another option would be to use the anchors:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1.00in, fill=cyan] (a) {}
node[rectangle,draw,fill=magenta,anchor=east] (b) at (a.west) {};
\node[rectangle,draw,fill=green,anchor=south] at (a.north) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know of the various options. Will try those. @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks again.

Comment: Some problems can appear with different line width for the different shapes, especially with anchors or with `left= -\pgflinewidth`